# tycho build, chmod action fails for linux/64 target

Tags: maven, rcp, chmod, tycho

i'm building a rcp-application with tycho (0.14.1) on a 64 bit ubuntu. for target os win32/64 the build works fine, but when i add linux/64 to the targets, the build fails with the following error:

Installing org.some.rcp.product 0.0.0.
Installation failed.
An error occurred while installing the items
 session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]org.some.rcp.product.executable.gtk.linux.x86_64 0.0.0, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.ChmodAction).
 The action chmod failed - file /home/user/workspace/some.rcp.product.tycho/target/products/some.rcp.product/linux/gtk/x86_64/launcher.svn-base does not exist

i have absolutely no clue why the svn string appears in here, there are no svn references at all in any project involved in the build.

any hints/solutions?

edit: i forgot to mention, i already tried to set a custom launcher name like described in here:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=349877 
didnt work for me

Comment: Is your project in an SVN repository? This seems to have been the root cause for a [similar error message](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=336963) in a different build system.

Answer (score 0):

don't know why, but adding the eclipse repo to my own target definition ([tycho-example-4](http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho-demo.git/tree/itp04-rcp/target-definition/helios.target) describes how) solved the problem.

Comment: If this really fixes the problem, it would be important to know which p2 repositories did you have in your target definition before you added the "eclipse repo".

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug. If you still can reproduce the problem, please post these steps as bug in the [Tycho issue tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/query.cgi?format=specific;product=Tycho).